# Кто занимается поддержкой русскоязычных участников?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow, миграция

Такая вот ситуация - старый аккаунт на хэшкоде регистрировал по 10minutemail (в то время вообще 99% сайтов регистрировал на нём, ибо не знал уровень полезности). Соответственно после перехода, зайти в аккаунт не могу. Вроде как написал в поддержку, мол не помню ни имени, ни пароля, объедините плиз. Ни ответа, ни привета. Мне в принципе параллельно, вопрос такой - администрированием русских аккаунтов занимаются русскоязычные сотрудники или нет?

Comment: "не помню не имени, ни пароля, объедините плиз" - что с чем? о_О

Comment: Нет конечно, все знают что они на самом деле искусственный интеллект огромного боевого человекоподобного робота из альтернативной вселенной основная цель которого подчинить все машины и механизмы в этом мире, чтобы построить портал обратно и спасти тот мир от нарастающей энтропии. Все просто же.

Comment: вспоминается прикол про создателей википедии - мол соберут все данные и укатят на свою планету

Comment: так как реализовать общение с админами?

Comment: Скажите, проблема с объединением аккаунтов ещё актуальна?

Answer (score 7):

По идее, должны отвечать на почту техподдержки. Не знаю, почему вы не получили ответа. Поставил флаг на вашем вопросе, должны как-то обработать.

Но если вы не помните ни имени, ни пароля, то что они будут объединять? Постарайтесь вспомнить хоть что-то.

По поводу вопроса о сотрудниках SO: есть Николай Чабановский, он единственный официально русскоязычный сотрудник на данный момент. Буржуями я бы не стал называть остальных. Эти люди создали и поддерживают SO, которым мы бесплатно пользуемся. Единственное, в чём их можно упрекнуть - отсутствие навыка телепатии.

Comment: **Да нет же, нужно следовать сеттингу.** Чтобы связаться с админом абонент должен воспользоваться встроенным нейрокибернетическим интерфейсом и подписать контракт. После сеанса связи он будет помещен в криокамеру(согласно пункту 2.5 параграфа 3 части 2 мелким шрифтом) где из него будет высосана вся энергия и необходимый биоматериал для поддержания миссии Skynet в этом мире.

Comment: @igumnov, вы подозрительно много знаете про объединение аккаунтов. Об этом будет доложено █████ ███████ и будут приняты соответствующие меры согласно служебному протоколу №43/██.

Comment: @Nofate Мистер Смит мы оба знаем что в этом нет смысла, т.к. при помещении подопытного в криокамеру после объединения аккаунтов в его мозг запускается симуляция реальности. Этот тред уже находится внутри неё и хуже того глубина рекурсии неизвестна..